# How to use libgpiod with buttons in a non-blocking fashion?

Tags: linux, gpio

I am trying to understand if it is possible to wait for button events in a non-blocking fashion with libgpiod?

I have looked through the API, specifically the ctxless event loops, but those all appear to poll in a blocking manner, with no ability to use a select callback.

Of note, this is a single core processor.

If the above cannot be accomplished, it appears my options are to write my own driver, create threads and rely on the scheduler to timeslice me to not block, or look more heavily into gpio-keys to interrupt me.

Comment: 1. Create another thread. 2. Wait for button in that thread. 3. Continue with your work in the thread you started from. Maybe you'll want `gpiod_line_event_wait`?

Comment: Ya, I believe this is the current option I am leaning towards. And yes, I currently use gpiod_line_event_wait, but I was missing the button presses because I was not blocking on it.

Comment: If believe if configured with `GPIOD_LINE_REQUEST_EVENT_*` the `gpiod_line_event_read` shouldn't be able to omit events.

Comment: Why not to use `gpio-keys` driver with a correct description in the first place? Otherwise, you may use event monitoring from `libgpiod` library in a separate thread in case you need to do something else while `poll()` is idling. Of course you may do everythin in mainloop, but it won't guarantee that you don't miss some events.